# How to simulate mv failing in a non-privileged Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, mv, container

An application inside a non-privileged Docker container executes `mv <source_file> <dest_dir>` under root, where `<source_file>` must be an existing regular file and `<dest_dir>` must be an existing directory. Other than that, there are no requirements on privileges, owner/group, file content etc.

What is the simplest way to setup an environment (only within the container), where this operation fails?

---

I tried read-only bind mount, which would result in a `Read-only file system` error, but that only works with the `--privileged` flag:

```bash
mount --bind -o ro foo dest_dir  # mount: /dest_dir: permission denied.
mv file dest_dir
```

I also tried creating a too-small filesystem, which would result in `No space left on device` error, but that also requires a mount, so it also works only with the `--privileged` flag:

```bash
dd if=/dev/zero of=device bs=1M count=10
mkfs.ext4 device
mount -o loop device dest_dir  # mount: dest_dir: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
mv big_file dest_dir
```

Comment: Why not use a [Docker Volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) mounted as read-only when running the test container?  `docker run -d -v /some/dir/on/host:/readonly:ro someimage`

Comment: I can only affect the inside of a container. I have no control over how it's created.